# CS5001 Program does not contain a static 'Main' method suitable for an entry point

Tags: c#

I am new to C#. I'd be thankful if any body can show me why the following error is shown for code.

"CS5001 Program does not contain a static 'Main' method suitable for an entry point"

```
using System;

class test
{
    void Foo(int x) { Console.WriteLine(x); }
    void Foo(double x) { Console.WriteLine(x); }
    void Foo(int x, float y) { Console.WriteLine(x); Console.WriteLine(y);}
    void Foo(float x, int y) { Console.WriteLine(x); Console.WriteLine(y); }

    void Main()
    {
        Foo(123);           // int
        Foo(123.0);     // double
        Foo(123, 123F); // int, float
        Foo(123F, 123); // float, int
    }
}
```

Comment: static void Main()

Comment: It's right there in the error message. You have a non-static `Main`. The error message says a **static** `Main` is missing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your fixed code should look like this:

```
using System;

class test
{
    static void Foo(int x) { Console.WriteLine(x); }
    static void Foo(double x) { Console.WriteLine(x); }
    static void Foo(int x, float y) { Console.WriteLine(x); Console.WriteLine(y); }
    static void Foo(float x, int y) { Console.WriteLine(x); Console.WriteLine(y); }

    static void Main()
    {
        Foo(123);       // int
        Foo(123.0);     // double
        Foo(123, 123F); // int, float
        Foo(123F, 123); // float, int
    }
}
```

Comment: An explanation as to why would make this answer better.

Comment: Thanks. Yogi and Daniel

Comment: So why isn’t the class named program?

Answer (score 4):

This error occurs when `Main` method is defined with incorrect signature. This error also occurs if `Main`, is defined with the wrong case, such as lower-case main.

> Main must be declared as static and it must return void or int, and it
>   must have either no parameters or else one parameter of type string[]

Define your main method like this -

```
static void Main()
```

OR like this -

```
static void Main(string[] args)
```

Have a look at [this link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1y814bzs.aspx) for more information

Answer (score 0):

Remove `<OutputType>Exe</OutputType>` in project file (.csproj)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you close your first,

```
static void checkAge (int age)
```

with the curly bracket

```
}
```

before opening the other

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
```

As seen:

```cs
using System;

namespace MyApplication
{
    class Program
    {
        static void checkAge(int age)
        {
            if (age < 18)
            {
                throw new ArithmeticException("Access denied - You must be at least 18 years old.");
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Access granted - You are old enough.");
            }
        }
            static void Main(string[] args) 
            {
                checkAge(20);
            }
    }
}
```